# What is the point in using Kademlia routing if there are so few nodes?

Tags: client, protocol

With about ~5000 full nodes, and given that this number will probably never grow too much (say, >1000000 full nodes is extremely inefficient and unlikely), then what is the point of using a Kademlia-like routing strategias? As far as I understand, for that scale just storing all nodes in all nodes is much simpler to program, and more efficient as messages can be sent in one hop from anyone to anyone.

Comment: Bitcoin does not use or need Kademlia or any other DHT scheme. It uses a gossip protocol that just floods all information to every node. Where does this question come from?

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for this information, @PieterWuille. I guess I was misinformed. It is very hard to find information regarding how Bitcoin's network works. Do all nodes keep track of every other node? Do you suggest any resource?

Comment: Nodes just connect to a bunch of random other nodes (typically 8), and announce new transactions and blocks to each other. Security depends on being connected to at least one honest node.